# How can I generate a html report based on a Rmarkdown including reactives plots?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-reactivity

I've developed a Rmarkdown report (report.Rmd) with reactive plot inside (like this [shiny.rstudio.com](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_interactive.html))

Now I would like to export the content as static report (report.html) via a shiny App and by choosing the desired values to show on the plot.
(like this [shiny.rstudio.com](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html), with the difference that I dont have parameters but input selected in the widget (input$bw_adjust).

Problem:

- With R version 4.2.3 (private PC): I can generate a report.html but there is not the plot.
- With R version 4.0.4 (business PC): No output generated: "Error in : path for html_dependency not provided [No stack trace available]"

```
---title: Report
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

# 1. Here the report.rmd

sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)


renderPlot({
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  plot(dens, col = "blue")
})
```

```
# 2. And here my app

library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput(
      "bw_adjust",
      label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
      min = 0.2,
      max = 2,
      value = 1,
      step = 0.2
    ),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.html",
      content = function(file) {
        rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", output_file = file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Shiny document is basically a shiny app and can only be run from within R or using a Shiny server to serve the document. There is no such thing as a static shiny document. As a consequence you end up with an HTML document which includes e.g. an input and even a container for the plot but is otherwise not working and hence you will see nothing.

Instead, to create a static report use a parameterized Rmd as shown in the link you referenced:

````
---
title: Report
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
params:
  bw_adjust: 1
---

```{r}
dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = params$bw_adjust)
plot(dens, col = "blue")
```
````

In your shiny app you could then pass the value chosen by the user to the Rmd report via the `params` argument of `rmarkdown::render`:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput(
      "bw_adjust",
      label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
      min = 0.2,
      max = 2,
      value = 1,
      step = 0.2
    ),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.html",
      content = function(file) {
        rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", output_file = file, params = list(bw_adjust = input$bw_adjust))
      }
    )
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your solution allows producing the report.html from report.rmd via the shiny app.R. However it deletes the reactive plot from report.rmd.

I suggest to complete the code in report.rmd

````
---
title: Report
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
params:
  bw_adjust: 1
---

# Conditional production of a widget in report.rmd
# depending on the function interactive()

```{r}

if(interactive()) {
    print("Static report generation activated!")
} else {
  print("Dynamic shiny activated!")
    sliderInput(
    "bw_adjust",
    label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
    min = 0.2,
    max = 2,
    value = 1,
    step = 0.2)
}


```
# Conditional production of a plot, with params or reactive input
# depending on the function interactive()

```{r}

if (interactive()) {
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = params$bw_adjust)
  plot(dens, col = "blue")
} else {
  renderPlot({
    dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
    plot(dens, col = "green")
  })
}
```
````